# Pyinstaller / auto-py-to-exe additional files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, face-recognition

I have a python script that uses the face_recognition library(as well as other libraries), and want to make an .exe file out of it. I use pyinstaller, but I get the following error when trying to run the .exe file:[image]

I guess it needs a hook or something, but I am not really familiar with how to write one or what the contents of it should be. I had a similar problem in the past with another python script I was trying to make into an .exe file, and luckily someone knew how to help me out. It would be great if someone could guide me through this.

Answer (score 2):

Since the exe is complaining about a missing module "pkg_resources.py2_warn2 add --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn to your build command

To complete the job you should read https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/357

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion fixed the problem I was having. But now I have a new complication. When trying to run the .exe file i get the following error : https://imgur.com/a/HHyvlUP  . The "face_recognition_models" folder isnt located inside the dist folder (obviously), but it tries to access it that way. That is **not** a problem I have with my original python script. Maybe I need some sort of parameter when using pyinstaller?

Comment: You need to figure out how the lib or you own py is accessing the model (I mean: absolute path, relative path, ...) and then --add-data option for the build command will help you.

Comment: @BillB I updated my answer with a link that might be usefull for your last issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make an .exe file with libarys, I would recommend using https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ auto-py-to-exe, i've used it many times and it works great.

Comment: I've tried using that before, but how do I know what to add to the additional files section? Furthermore, to avoid future confusion, how do I know what additional files will be needed when trying to create a .exe file from a python script?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
I fixed this by adding the required libraries to the python environment that auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller uses

Answer (score -2):

Use auto py to exe, easy to use, disable the anti-virus run its installation code and then load it.remember to add the library path to additional files option of auto py to exe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33927565)